# Python. Проблемма с кодировкой после BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, кодировка, beautiful-soup

Написал небольшой парсер для одного сайта и вроде всё работает, но возникает проблема с одной страницей. Ответ запроса вроде как utf8. По крайне мере файл записывается в utf8 кодировке, корректно отображается на консоле и заголовок страницы тоже отдаёт utf8

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Но вот после парсинга в BeautifulSoup текст выдаёт кракозябрами и пишет, что кодировка maccyrillic. Пол дня убил, что бы понять откуда растут ноги у проблемы и как это исправить. Я сдался. Может тут есть опытные люди, которые помогут... Сам код:

```
def проверка_сообщений(сессия, ссылка_для_проверки, заголовки):
    ответ = сессия.get(ссылка_для_проверки, headers=заголовки)
    ответ.encoding = 'utf8'
    объявления = BS(ответ.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf8")
    print(объявления.original_encoding)
    print(объявления.title)

    with open("index.html", "w") as file:
        file.write(ответ.text)
```

Консоль:

```
maccyrillic
<title>–Ь–Њ–Є –Њ–±—К—П–≤–ї–µ–љ–Є—П</title>
```

Comment: А какой `User-Agent` вы передаете в заголовках? Там ОС случайно не *Mac*?

Comment: @Стас `"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0"`

Смешно то, что я даже явно везде указал использовать utf8, но результат это не изменило. И проблема только с одной страницей, которую парсю в учётке после авторизации. Другие страницы с объявлениями парсятся нормально и без явных указаний кодировки в коде

Comment: К сожалению, проблема не воспроизводится. Могу посоветовать установить заголовок `{"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"}`. Согласно документации, установка `ответ.encoding` влияет на поведение `ответ.text`, но не на `ответ.content`. Возможно, стоит заменить `BS(ответ.content, ...` на `BS(ответ.text, ...` и убрать `from_encoding`. Если ничего не поможет - есть выход через: `объявления.title.encode("mac-cyrillic").decode("utf-8")`. Не думаю, что это лучшее решение, но временно это вас спасет.

Comment: `{"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"}` -  не привело моментально к нужному результату, но дало пищу для размышлений и разработки на завтрашний день. А вот: `BS(ответ.text, ...` привело кодировку в читаемый вид и можно считать за ответ. Так же `объявления.title.encode("mac-cyrillic").decode("utf-8")` тоже позволило прочесть заголовок. Но первый вариант мне больше нравится. Пишите ответ :) Жаль, что не прояснился вопрос с тем откуда это вообще всё вылезло (проблема с кодировкой). Завтра попробую ещё с заголовками поковыряться

Comment: @Стас Сегодня сайт на котором я делал срез данных изменил код страницы и теперь всё нужное я могу получить напрямую из JSON и не парсить саму страницу. Более того делать парсинг вообще нет смысла, т.к. данные на страницу уже подставляются из JSON динамически. Похоже вчера я неудачно попал на обновления кода той страницы. В любом случае это помогло мне глубже взглянуть на некоторые вещи. И спасибо Стасу за помощь